# Let $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ be a continuous function and$g:[a,b]\to\Bbb R, g(x)=\sup\{f(t):a\le t\le x\}.$ Show $g$ is a continuous function over $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis

I am a 31-year-old college student trying to study from some practice exam materials that my professor has given me. I will include an example of one of the problems I am struggling with.

> Let $f: [a,b] \rightarrow  \Bbb R$ be a continuous function and define $$g: [a,b] \rightarrow \Bbb R, \quad g(x)= \sup\{f(t): a\leq t\leq x\}.$$

I am supposed to show that $g$ is a continuous function over $[a,b]$. I recall doing this by showing that $g$ is a monotone function or something along those lines but I am not quite sure how to proceed with this.

I am stuck with what it is exactly that I need to show to prove that g is continuous.

Comment: Hi CatastrophicDiaspora! Your question is great, though I must make the small note that $g$ is most likely monotone, not monotonous...

Comment: $g$ is indeed monotonically increasing, however you are asked to show that $g$ is continuous. Monotonicity doesn't imply continuity.

Comment: Welcome!  You want to make your question title a lot more specific, and maybe add more separate questions.  Make sure to show what you have tried and exactly where you are stuck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Rising sun" function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557100/rising-sun-function)

Comment: As always in math, a good place to start is definitions. Write out exactly the definition of $g$ being continuous.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Robert. So after writing out the definition of g being continuous, my next step would then be to show that if it is monotonically increasing that it must be continuous over [a,b]? That is where I am the most stuck.

Comment: I am still stuck on how to show that g is monotone. I emailed my professor and he said that I should first start by showing g is monotone. Do I just need to show that g_x $\leq$ g_x+1?

Comment: @CatastrophicDiaspora Not sufficient. In fact you shall show that $g(x) \leqslant g(y)$ whenever $x < y$, not only the case when $y = x + 1$.

Comment: Ok that is more helpful. What would that look like? Can I just show that for any x<y, that g(y) will give me an upper bound which will be bigger than g(x)?

Comment: There's a theorem that says "If $I\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is an interval and $g : I \to \mathbb{R}$ is monotonic, then $g$ is continuous if and only if $g$ has the intermediate value property".  If your professor is saying you should first show $g$ is monotonic, then he probably wants you to use that.

Comment: That $g$ is monotonic increasing relies on the fact: For any subsets $A$, $B$ of $\mathbb{R}$, if $A\subseteq B$, then $\sup(A)\leq \sup(B)$.

Comment: The proof of the above claim: If $A$ is empty, then $\sup(A)=-\infty$ by convention and we are done. Suppose that $A$ is non-empty. Let $x\in A$ be arbitrary. Since $A\subseteq B$, we have that $x\in B$. It follows that $x\leq \sup(B)$. This shows that $\sup(B)$ is an upper bound of $A$. Hence, it is larger than or equal to the least upper bound of $A$. That is, $\sup(A) \leq \sup(B)$.

Answer (score -1):

We need for all $\epsilon$ a $\delta$

$$|g(x)-g(x+h)|<\epsilon, |\delta|<h$$

$$\Leftrightarrow |\sup\{f(t): a\leq t\leq x\}-\sup\{f(t): a\leq t\leq x+h\}|<\epsilon, h<|\delta|$$

Immediately by continuity we have a $\delta$ such that $$|f(x)-f(x+h)|<\epsilon/2, h<|\delta|$$

$$...\leq|\sup\{f(t): a\leq t\leq x\}-\sup\{f(t): a\leq t\leq x\}|+|\epsilon/2|<\epsilon, h<|\delta|$$

Answer (score -1):

Clearly $g$ is monotonic increasing. Therefore, for any $x\in(a,b)$,
the left-hand limit $g(x-)=\lim_{y\rightarrow x-}g(y)$ and right-hand
limit $\lim_{y\rightarrow x+}g(y)$ exist. Moreover, $g(x-)\leq g(x)\leq g(x+)$
and $g$ is continuous at $x$ iff $g(x-)=g(x+)$.

Let $x_{0}\in(a,b)$. We go to prove that $g$ is continuous at $x_{0}$.
Prove by contradiction. Suppose that $g$ is not continuous at $x_{0}$,
then $l:=g(x_{0}+)-g(x_{0}-)>0$. Since $f$ is continuous at $x_{0}$,
we may choose $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(x_{0})|<\frac{l}{4}$
whenever $x\in(x_{0}-\delta,x_{0}+\delta)$. For any $x\in[a,x_{0}+\frac{\delta}{2}]$,
if $x\in[a,x_{0}]$, we clearly have $f(x)\leq g(x_{0})$. If $x\in(x_{0},x_{0}+\frac{\delta}{2}]$,
then $f(x)\leq f(x_{0})+\frac{l}{4}\leq g(x_{0})+\frac{l}{4}$. Hence,
$f(x)\leq g(x_{0})+\frac{l}{4}$ for all $x\in[a,x_{0}+\frac{\delta}{2}]$.
That is, $g(x_{0}+\frac{\delta}{2})\leq g(x_{0})+\frac{l}{4}$.

For any $x\in[a,x_{0}]$, if $x\in[a,x_{0}-\frac{\delta}{2}]$, then
$f(x)\leq g(x_{0}-\frac{\delta}{2})$. If $x\in(x_{0}-\frac{\delta}{2},x_{0}]$,
then
\begin{eqnarray*}
|f(x)-f(x_{0}-\frac{\delta}{2})| & \leq & |f(x)-f(x_{0})|+|f(x_{0})-f(x_{0}-\frac{\delta}{2})|\\
 & < & \frac{l}{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore, $f(x)\leq f(x_{0}-\frac{\delta}{2})+\frac{l}{2}\leq g(x_{0}-\frac{\delta}{2})+\frac{l}{2}$. Hence $f(x) \leq g(x_{0}-\frac{\delta}{2})+\frac{l}{2}$ for all $x\in[a,x_{0}]$. It follows that $g(x_{0})\leq g(x_{0}-\frac{\delta}{2})+\frac{l}{2}$.

Finally,
\begin{eqnarray*}
l & = & g(x_{0}+)-g(x_{0}-)\\
 & \leq & g(x_{0}+\frac{\delta}{2})-g(x_{0}-\frac{\delta}{2})\\
 & = & [g(x_{0}+\frac{\delta}{2})-g(x_{0})]+[g(x_{0})-g(x_{0}-\frac{\delta}{2})]\\
 & \leq & \frac{l}{4}+\frac{l}{2}\\
 & < & l,
\end{eqnarray*}
which is a contradiction.

The proof for the case that $x_{0}=a$ or $x_{0}=b$ can be modified
accordingly.