# Supremum and Continuity for function

Tags: continuity, supremum-and-infimum, monotone-functions, bounded-variation

Let $f$ be continuous on $[a, b]$. Define a function $g$ as follows: $g(a)=f(a)$ and, for $x$
in $(a, b]$ $$g(x)=\sup \{f(y): y \text { in }[a, x]\}$$
Prove that $g$ is monotone increasing and continuous on $[a, b]$.

Regarding the monotone increasing, if $g(x) < g(y)$ for some $x,y$ then using the fact that supremum of any set is greater than or equal to the supremum of any subset of it, we will reveal that $g$ is a non-decreasing function. However, I could not come up with how "monotone increasing" can be deduced; moreover, how one could prove the continuity of $g$ without using the epsilon-delta definition: are there any direct features we could apply in this particular problem?

Comment: Are there any first-step ideas about what could be improved more upon? Maybe another strategy would be much applicable for the case of monotone increasing, and how one should think about the continuity of function $g$?

Comment: Same question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4084893/let-fa-b-to-bbb-r-be-a-continuous-function-andga-b-to-bbb-r-gx-sup

Comment: @absolute0 If you carefully check the link, it will be noticed that the solutions provided are neither fully correct nor provide true insights about the given problem. There seems to be a lot of missing parts there. But thanks again!

Comment: Can anyone also suggest further ideas for this problem? The link above does not contain correct solutions, and the below solution seems to be indeed correct; however, more mathematical rigor is desired since there are some ambiguities at the end part especially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your deduction for monotonic increment of $g(x)$ is correct as $[a,x_1]\subset[a,x_2]$ for $x_1<x_2$. For continuity, you must prove that
$$
|x_2-x_1|<\delta\implies |g(x_2)-g(x_1)|<\epsilon
.
$$
Arbitrarily let $x_2>x_1$. Hence
$$
g(x_2)=\sup_{y\in[a,x_2]}f(y)=\max\left\{\sup_{y\in[a,x_1]}f(y),\sup_{y\in(x_1,x_2]}f(y)\right\}
=\max\left\{g(x_1),\sup_{y\in(x_1,x_2]}f(y)\right\},
$$
hence
$$
g(x_2)-g(x_1)=\max\left\{0,\sup_{y\in(x_1,x_2]}f(y)-g(x_1)\right\}.
$$
The rest of the proof should now be easy due to the continuity of $f(x)$ over $(x_1,x_2]$.

Comment: Could you please clarify on the final part, since it seems true about the continuity of $f(x)$ over the range $(x_1, x_2]$ but I could not relate how it could be applied to the max of zero and sup value?! Especially, if sup $f(y) - g(x_1)$ is greater than zero, how continuity could be incorporated to make the difference $g(x_2) - g(x_1)$ as small as possible from the delta relation?

Comment: Use the fact that when $x_2\to x_1$, then $f(x_2)\to f(x_1)$ and note that there are two cases, either $g(x_1)\ge \sup_{y\in(x_1,x_2]}f(y)$ or $g(x_1)< \sup_{y\in(x_1,x_2]}f(y)$.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply about the elaboration. Honestly, I also do understand that there exist 2 possibilities for $g(x_1)$ and sup $f(y)$; however, the relation between this comparison and our problem seems to me really obscure from the mathematical perspective. Moreover, I also started to doubt my proof for the increasing, since my proof is only valid for non-decreasing because the sup of subset could be equal to the original set's supremum value. Could really appreciate it if you provide more insights and details on these parts, please.