# What does the notation $\,\max_{t \le\ x}(t^3 - 3t)\,$ mean, and how do I graph it for $x\leq2$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions, maxima-minima

This was a part of a bigger problem that I was solving. I had to graph the following definition for $x\le2$.
$$\max_{t \le\ x}(t^3 - 3t)$$
I do not understand how to graph this. What does this notation mean?

Comment: It is a "rising sun" function (imagine the sun at −∞ on the x axis lighting the scene) as here math.stackexchange.com/q/557100/305862. Its graph is the graph of f where the little loop below the line segment [0,3] on the x axis is replaced by this line segment.

Comment: The concept behind that is "maximal value obtained so far" (i.e., till time $x$) which is familiar to sportmen/women (and computer scientists). If you "underperform" your "max so far" remains at the same level till you "break your own record again".

Comment: Oh I think I got it. The function is increasing in (−∞, -1). So the "maximal value obtained so far" till x=-1 has not "underperformed". But after x = -1, the function decreases and the maximal value then remains 2 only and it "underperforms" till x =2. I have linked the graphs below. The graph of function https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kdtvshakpw The graph of max function https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fcvmnm0wzp

Comment: You should now validate one of the two answers you have received. Leaving non-validated answers causes problems...

Answer (score 2):

The given expression is a function of $x$. Denote it by $f(x) = \max_{t\leq x} (t^3-3t)$. Now solve this maximization in the usual manner (derivatives and such). Notice: the maximization is with respect to $t$ (so you have $g(t) = t^3-3t$, and you're finding maximum of $g$ in the interval $(-\infty, x]$) and that $x$ appears as the upper bound on the interval so you have to take that into consideration when finding the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Function

$$g(x)=\max_{x \le t}f(t)$$

should be interpreted as "the best value obtained **so far**" ("so far" means here "till time $x$")... a way of thinking very familiar to sportmen/women.

Therefore, as the graph of $f$ is increasing on $(-\infty,-1)$, on all this interval, the best performance so far is the present performance. But, on the segment $(-1,1)$, the graph of $f$ "delves". The "best performance so far" is the value of the last "peak", i.e. $f(-1)=2$. Past "time" $x=1$, the performance becomes anew above value $2$ (one begins to "break his own record(s)"), which means that one has again to stick to the present value of $x$.

Passing from $f$ to $g$ is sometimes called the "rising sun" transformation : imagine (in this case, it is no longer a sport mataphor, but a geographical analogy) the sun at $-\infty$ on the $x$ axis lighting the graph of function $f$) as considered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557100/rising-sun-function), with horizontal rays over the valleys... You can think as well to a flood analogy: all valleys have been flooded and transformed into lakes...

Conclusion: $g(x)=f(x)$ everywhere but for $x \in (-1,1)$ where its value stays at $f(-1)=2$.

Remark : "best value so far" is also familiar to computer scientists : it is the usual way to get - at the end - a global maximum when parsing a list of numbers.